# Съезжает два блока при уменьшении окна браузера

Tags: css, вёрстка

```html
<h1 style="padding-left: 1000px;">                                Инженерные системы под ключ</h1>

<hr />

<h1 style="padding-left: 1040px;">          <a href="https://xn----8sbnahitmfedahg7bl.xn--p1ai/?page_id=61">Водоснабжение </a>                              <a href="https://xn----8sbnahitmfedahg7bl.xn--p1ai/?page_id=61">Отопление</a>
<img class="size-full wp-image-230 alignleft" src="https://xn----8sbnahitmfedahg7bl.xn--p1ai/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/desatascos-tuberias-d03f1f02-e1631822867768.png" alt="" width="600" height="400" /><img class="size-full wp-image-214 alignleft" src="https://xn----8sbnahitmfedahg7bl.xn--p1ai/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/depositphotos_76853285-stock-photo-floor-heating-system-the-collector-10.jpg" alt="" width="600" height="400" /></h1>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), у вас страница регистрации на домене

Comment: Добавил код на страницу